# Azure - WebJob timeout when calling stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

I have a webjob that calls a long running stored procedure that keeps timing out. Can anyone help please?

The web job is called using the following code:

```
    static void Main()
    {
        ApplicationDbContext context = new ApplicationDbContext();

        context.Database.CommandTimeout = 6000;

        context.PopulateJobTypeDescendants();

    }
```

The method on the context (ApplicationDbContext) is shown below:

```
    public void PopulateJobTypeDescendants()
    {
        Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("PopulateJobTypeDescendants");
    }
```

The following exception is raised when the web job is run. We have read that it could be related to the plan/DTUs on the server so we went from S1 -> S3, this still didn't solve the issue and the process bombs out after 45 seconds. The strange thing is that if I connect to azure sql db from SSMS and call the stored procedure it works fine.

> [07/11/2016 22:25:02 > e2cf50: ERR ] Unhandled Exception:
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Timeout expired.  The timeout
>   period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is
>   not responding.  This failure occurred while attempting to connect to
>   the routing destination. The duration spent while attempting to
>   connect to the original server was - [Pre-Login] initialization=14;
>   handshake=26; [Login] initialization=0; authentication=0; [Post-Login]
>   complete=1;   ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The wait
>   operation timed out

The connection string is shown below:

```
<add name="TempsContext" connectionString="Server=tcp:[XXX],1433;Database=temps_testing;User ID=[XXX];Password=[XXX];Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;Connection Timeout=600;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that this is caused by some inconsistencies in how EF propagates the value of `CommandTimeout` to the commands its creates, e.g. to do database initialization or to obtain versioning information from the server.

It should be possible to use command interception as a workaround, e.g.:

```c#
using System.Data.Common;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception;

namespace CommandTimeOutBug
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DbInterception.Add(new MyInterceptor());

            using (var context = new ApplicationDbContext())
            {

                context.Database.CommandTimeout = 6000;

                context.PopulateJobTypeDescendants();
            }
        }
    }

    public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
    {

        public void PopulateJobTypeDescendants()
        {
           Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("PopulateJobTypeDescendants");
        }
    }

    public class MyInterceptor: DbCommandInterceptor
    {

        public override void NonQueryExecuting(DbCommand command, 
            DbCommandInterceptionContext<int> interceptionContext)
        {
            command.CommandTimeout = 6000;
            base.NonQueryExecuting(command, interceptionContext);
        }

        public override void ReaderExecuting(DbCommand command, 
            DbCommandInterceptionContext<DbDataReader> interceptionContext)
        {
            command.CommandTimeout = 6000;
            base.ReaderExecuting(command, interceptionContext);
        }

        public override void ScalarExecuting(DbCommand command, 
            DbCommandInterceptionContext<object> interceptionContext)
        {
            command.CommandTimeout = 6000;
            base.ScalarExecuting(command, interceptionContext);
        }
    }
}
```

I have created a bug at https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework6/issues/24 to track this.